# CSS Sprite - Does the image is loaded everytime I call a class

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have my HTML where I have added famfamfam sprite:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/famfamfam.css">
```

My CSS has styles like this:

```
.fam{display:inline-block;height:16px;width:16px;background:url('../images/famfamfam.png') no-repeat 0 0;vertical-align:baseline;}

.fam.accept{background-position: -0px -0px}
.fam.add{background-position: -16px -0px}
.fam.anchor{background-position: -32px -0px}
```

So in order to add an image is can do somethign like this:

```
<span class="fam add">Hello</span>
```

I know my question might sound very dumb, but:

> Does every time that I add a  element does the famfamfam.png is loaded? Or how does sprite works? I don't want to over kill my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

- The browser will not re-download the sprite image again if you use multiple elements with the .fam class on a page.
- If your server is configured well, the browser will cache the image after it's downloaded and on subsequent page views, it'll reuse the cached image instead of re-downloading.

So, as long as the sprite's main .png is a reasonable size, nothing to worry about.

Comment: The image size is 200kb- Is that ok?

Comment: That's actually very large for an icon sprite sheet. How many are you actually going to use? If the answer is "not that many," it's probably worth it to make a custom image that only includes the one you need. But if your site is very light on other assets and will use lots of icons, then 200kb for a major part of the visual design is not too big a deal.

Comment: I like your feedback about just creating a new image with only the icons that the app will use. Do you know a way to create a sprite image from other sprite? or a sprite from icons? Im using famfamfam

Comment: I don't know one offhand, but if you Google "sprite generator" I bet you'll find free web apps that let you upload just the ones you need and generate the sprite sheet and CSS for you.